# PowerShell script to add domain user to multiple servers with results (success / failure)

Tags: powershell, sqlps

I am a PowerShell newbie and I am having trouble with a script.
Basically, I have created a script that will add a sysadmin to multiple SQL servers listed in a text file.  The text file is just one column of server names.  The script seems to work fine.

I would like to have a report stating if it failed on any of the servers in the list.  This could be csv or text.  I just don't want to assume the script ran fine on 100+ servers to only find out later that there were issues with the account or server.

This the script I am using:

```
Import-Module -Name SqlPs
$servers = Get-Content -Path C:\Temp\servers.txt
$servers |
   foreach{ `
      Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $_ `
            -Database 'Master'  `
            -Query "EXEC master..sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = N'DOMAIN\USERNAME', @rolename = N'sysadmin';" `
            -QueryTimeout 10 `
   }
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest wrapping your command in a try/catch block to aggregate the failures:

```
Import-Module -Name SqlPs

$errors = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]@()

$params = @{
    Database     = 'Master'
    Query        = "EXEC master..sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = N'DOMAIN\USERNAME', @rolename = N'sysadmin';"
    QueryTimeout = 10
    ErrorAction  = 'Stop'
}
foreach ($server in Get-Content -Path C:\Temp\servers.txt) {
    try {
        Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $server @params
    } catch {
        $errors.Add("$server failed: $_")
    }
}

$errors > errors.log
```

The most important thing here is `ErrorAction:Stop` which will turn your command into a *terminating* error to be caught by the try/catch block.

Comment: Thanks so much!
It worked great.  I am no guru so I might have been looking in the wrong place but I had to add a path to the errors.log file.
I have been working on this since yesterday and I could not get try/catch, if else or any other syntax to work.
Thanks Again...So Much!

Comment: Another option is to enumerate over the `$Error` global object and record each item that way @JamesBenton